# Testing hypothesis for a fraction

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

Let's say I have a sample of $70$ people rating a book from $1$ to $5$:
$n_1 = 5$
$n_2 = 8$
$n_3 = 20$
$n_4 = 31$
$n_5 = 6$
Where $n_i$ is a number of people who gave a rating $i$. I have to obtain a p-value of a test that verifies:

$\begin{cases}H_0: 40\% \text{ of people give a rating of at least 3}\\
H_1: \text{<40% of people give a rating of at least 3}\end{cases}$

How should I approach this kind of a problem? I thought of Karlin-Rubin theorem but I'm not sure if it is the right path?

Comment: Your outcome of interest is binary (20+31+6 = 57 people out of 70 rated the book a 3 or more).  Why not apply a binomial test to this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your $n_i$ notation correctly, you have $x =57$ out of $n = 70$ people giving a rating of at least `3`. Your observed proportion rating at least '3' is $57/70 =  0.8143 > 0.4.$ Thus, it makes no sense to use a *left*-sided alternative, as in $H_0: p = 0.4$ against $H_a: p < 0.4.$
The evidence is that $p$ may be as great as $\approx 0.8.$

If you do a left-sided test, you will get a P-value far above 5%, indicating that you cannot reject $H_0.$

An exact test in R using the binomial CDF is 'binom.test'; it gives a P-value $\approx 1.$

```
binom.test(x=57, n = 70, p=.4, alt="less")

        Exact binomial test

data:  57 and 70
number of successes = 57, number of trials = 70, p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is less than 0.4
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.0000000 0.8865042
sample estimates:
probability of success 
             0.8142857
```

The P-value in the test above is computed as follows:

```
pbinom(57, 50, .4)
[1] 1
```

In the figure below, one can see that nearly 100% of the probability
in the distribution $\mathsf{Binom}(n= 70, p = .4)$ lies below 57

[image]